# Format particular terminal nodes and remove lines between them and their parents using forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, linguistics, trees

When using the [`forest`](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package to draw linguistic syntax trees, how can one prevent lines being drawn between particular terminal nodes and their parents, while still maintaining them as separate "nodes" as viewed by `forest`/`TikZ` in order to facilitate programmatic formatting?

Here is an example of the desired output (produced using my current workaround as given in the MWE below):

[image: example-desired-output-tree]

My current workaround involves the following which requires too much manual intervention:

- I remove lines between a "terminal node" and its "parent" by creating a single node and then forcing a line break between the syntactic category (if present) and its lexical realisation (if present), e.g. `[DP\\the apple]`.
- Terminal nodes that have lexical items have these items manually decorated by colouring them with the `xcolor` package (e.g. `[DP\\\textcolor{blue}{the apple}]`.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to programmatically apply something like the following code inside the `forest` environment:

```tex
for tree={
    if n children=0{
        text=blue
    }{},
}
```

However, adding the above snippet produces the following undesired output:

[image: example-undesired-output-tree]

I figure the solution might have something to do with setting up a type of "lexical terminal node" (i.e. terminal nodes that are of a lexical type instead of empty or a syntactic category), and then only applying the text decoration to nodes of that type. However, I'm not sure how to do this within `forest`, or if it is good/optimal solution.

**Minimal Working Example (current workaround)**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ----- Package Imports -----
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools} % Math enhancements
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath} % Palatino fonts (load after amssymb)
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Custom colours
%\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex} % Bibliography
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest} % Linguistic syntax trees

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [CP
        [\phantom{X}]
        [C'
            [C]
            [TP 
                [\phantom{X},name=TP-spec]
                [T'
                    [T\\\textcolor{blue}{$\varnothing_{\text{past}}$},name=TP-head]
                    [VoiceP 
                        [DP\\\textcolor{blue}{Bill}]
                        {\draw[->] () to[out=south west,in=west,distance=2cm] (TP-spec);}
                        [Voice' 
                            [Voice\\\textcolor{blue}{$\varnothing_{\text{active}}$}]
                            [VP 
                                [DP]
                                [V'
                                    [V\\{[}FORM preterite{]}\\\textcolor{blue}{ate}]
                                    [DP\\\textcolor{blue}{the apple}]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying `no edge` to a node prevents the edge to its parent being drawn.

The combination of `l sep=0` on the parent node and `l=0` on the child node gets them vertically close to each other.

I find the result most pleasing if I additionally set `inner ysep=0` on the child (this gets the category and lexical content even a bit closer), and override Forest's `align` (which puts the node content in a  `tabular` environment, and thereby creates some extra vertical space) by TikZ's `align`: `\forestset{align/.style={/tikz/align={#1}}}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ----- Package Imports -----
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Custom colours
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools} % Math enhancements
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath} % Palatino fonts (load after amssymb)
%\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex} % Bibliography
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest} % Linguistic syntax trees

\forestset{align/.style={/tikz/align={#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    if n children=1{
      l sep=0,
      for 1={no edge, l=0, inner ysep=0, blue}
    }{},
  }
    [CP
        [\phantom{X}]
        [C'
            [C]
            [TP 
                [\phantom{X},name=TP-spec]
                [T'
                    [T[$\varnothing_{\text{past}}$,name=TP-head]]
                    [VoiceP 
                        [DP[Bill]
                          {\draw[->] () to[out=south west,in=west,distance=2cm] (TP-spec);}
                        ]
                        [Voice' 
                            [Voice[$\varnothing_{\text{active}}$]]
                            [VP 
                                [DP]
                                [V'
                                    [V\\{[}FORM preterite{]}[ate]]
                                    [DP[the apple]]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: effect of modifications on typeset tree]

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the huge effort developing such a great package. Adjusting the `inner ysep=0` yields a much better result. Overriding Forest's `align` via TikZ works well; however, it seems a little cramped (e.g. the arrow from "Bill" to the TP specifier has its tail almost touching the word "Bill"), is there a way to add some padding to resolve this? All good if there isn't, this solution works great as it is!

Comment: Crampiness of the arrow is due to `inner ysep=0`. A workaround could be to manually shift the arrow a bit; for example, `{\draw[->] ([yshift=-2pt].base) to[out=south west,in=west,distance=2cm] (TP-spec.center);}` (I also included `.center` for TP-spec, I find it nicer.)

Comment: Perfect! Those options have given me the ability to manipulate the arrow placement a lot better now. One last issue I've encountered using this solution is that the formatting only works for trees that maintain binary branches. For example, this tree illustrates the issue between the NegP and Neg' nodes:
`[CP [\phantom{X}] [C' [C][TP [\phantom{X}] [T' [T [did]] [NegP [Neg' [Neg [not]] [VoiceP [DP [Bill]] [Voice' [Voice [$\varnothing_{\text{active}}$]] [VP [eat the apple]]]]]]]]]]`.
How would one edit the conditional to check if the current node has one child, and that child has no children?

Comment: In general, one can use pgfmath to test for options of a non-current node, e.g. `if={n_children("!1")==0}{true keys}{false keys}` test whether the first child has any children. However, in your case, the following works just fine: `for tree={if n children=1{for 1={if n children=0{for parent={l sep=0}, no edge, l=0, inner ysep=0, blue}{}}}{}}`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Achieved the exact result I needed.